# Finding an isomorphism between $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]\big/(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$ and $\mathbf Z\big/3$

Tags: ideals

> Finding an isomorphism between $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]\big/(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$ and $\mathbf Z\big/3$ ?

In general how does the elements of the ideal $(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$ look like,

in the form $(3)\cup(1-\sqrt{-5})$ ?

Comment: You shouldn't perform union of ideals, you should make sum of ideals instead.

Comment: The union of two ideals is not an ideal, unless one of them is contained in the other.

Comment: @Crostul can you give an example is $3a+c-(3b-c)\sqrt{-5}$ a general element of that ideal ? (with $a,b,c\in\mathbf Z$) ?

Answer (score 2):

As $\;\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]\simeq\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2+5)$,
 \begin{align*}\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]/(3,1-\sqrt{-5})&\simeq\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2+5)\boldsymbol/(3,1-X)\cdot\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2+5)\\
&\simeq\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2+5)\boldsymbol/(3,1-X,X^2+5)/(X^2+5)\\
&\simeq\mathbf Z[X]/(3,1-X,X^2+5)\simeq\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[X]/(1-X,X^2+5) \\
&\simeq\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[X]/(1-X,X^2-1).
\end{align*}
As $X^2-1\in(1-X)$, the ideal $(1-X,X^2-1)$ is simply $(1-X)$, so this is finally the same as
$$\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[X]/(1-X)\simeq\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z.$$

Explicitly, the isomorphism maps an element $a+b\sqrt{-5}\;$ to $\;a+b\bmod3$.